# Setting state of parent component in child component (where it's used as a prop) via Context API - does not trigger componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

A parent component - `App` is wrapped with a `Context.Provider` - that passes down the `App`'s State. 
A child `Counter` component is rendered via a HOC, its argument is a State variable passed from the `App` component. 
A click on the child component - changes that state variable, **via the Context API**; 
The child component **does in-fact rerenders** - 
but, `componentDidUpdate` is not triggered 
**Why?** 
I suspect it's related to React's shallow comparison... 
How can I make `componentDidUpdate` trigger - while still using this pattern?

Code example (also on Codepen: https://codepen.io/yuval_a/pen/YzPgBQV)

```
const StateContext  = React.createContext();
const StateProvider = StateContext.Provider;

const renderChild = num=> {

  class Counter extends React.Component {
    static contextType = StateContext;

    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      console.log ("Component updated");
    }

    click = ()=> {
      this.context.setAppState({ counter: this.context.appState.counter+1 });
    }
    render() {
      return <div onClick={this.click}>{ this.props.counter }</div>
    }
  }
  return <Counter counter={num} />
}

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          counter: 0
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StateProvider value={{
                appState: this.state,
                setAppState: newState=>{ this.setState(newState) }
            }}>

            { renderChild(this.state.counter) }
            </StateProvider>
        );
    }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `renderChild` is **invoked on every render**.

Therefore, `Counter` is actually unmounted on every render instead of getting updated as you expect, so the `DidUpdate` life cycle never kicks in.

```
const renderChild = num => {
  class Counter extends React.Component {
    // Called on every render
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('mounted on every render');
    }

    ...
    render() {
      return (...);
    }
  }
  return <Counter counter={num} />;
};
```

[image: Edit muddy-fog-so3on]

To fix it, you need to mount `Counter` once in his parent component.

Comment: Right. thanks. I need to remember not to call HOC functions from `render`!